# matplotlib inline facecolor not working on savefig

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to get my jupyter/python/%matplotlib charts to work with a dark background. I want to set a white background color for the full image rather than the default transparent.

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.savefig('dummy.png', facecolor='w', transparent=False)
```

The standard response is to use facecolor, but that isn't doing the trick [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DgjW.jpg).

Comment: try`plt.savefig('dummy.png', facecolor='w', transparent=False)`

Comment: That gives the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly set the rcParams and see if it does the trick:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["figure.facecolor"] = 'w'
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.savefig('dummy.png', transparent=False)
```

Also, the figure you showed us is already with a white facecolor. If it were transparent it would like like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGqGM.png).

Comment: OK, then what am I missing for something like https://imgur.com/a/TJkcB?

Comment: @BenKester, nothing actually. My codes gives exactly this figure you just linked. Could you show me what does it looks like in your computer?

Comment: *sigh* I keep getting the first image which doesn't show correctly on something like imgur. The rcParams doesn't do anything either.
It looks like the image in the original post.

Comment: @BenKester, try using `facecolor = 'm'` which will change the facecolor to Magenta, making it easier to see, then show me what is the output.

Comment: The facecolor setting has no effect. https://imgur.com/a/m8wnI. It's a white chart surrounded by black.

Comment: What about changing the last line to `fig.savefig('dummy.png', facecolor="m", transparent=False)` ?

Comment: You see that it is not actually surrounded by black, right? It is just imgur cropping it for display. If you zoom in you see the entire plot. But yes, it is not magenta like it should be https://imgur.com/0eV8LTW. What is the version of your matplotib?

Comment: Version 1.5.3. Oh that's really odd. The image shows up the same way with the Windows default image viewer but then when I pulled up Paint it shows the entire plot. And that's what I really care about.

Comment: I'm currently using matplotlib version 2.0.2. Try updating yours using pip(or pip3 if you are using Python 3).

Comment: I'm a bit lost on this issue. Is it really that the `facecolor` argument is not working correctly? In that case we need a [mcve] (including versions, way of running the code, backend in use etc.) such that it can be reported as bug and fixed. Or is this some other issue?

Comment: Upgrading to matplotlib 2.1.0 didn't help. I'll try it on another computer and report back.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's just my computer. Maybe I need a fresh install.

Answer (score 2):

`savefig` has separate entries in rcParams:

`plt.rcParams['savefig.facecolor'] = 'black'`